Why are the withdrawal limits at index funds so low?
I've heard that 90% of the stock market is HFT and another 90% is index funds. This would limit liquidity. However the withdrawal on vanguard funds is less than 10 million.
Even on a trillion dollar stock 1% of yearly volume is $10b. It shouldn't be dramatically, massively restrictive on liquidity to the point where nobody can sell $10m.

I've heard that 90% of the stock market is HFT and another 90% is index funds - that's 180%, of what exactly? Your question is not very clear. What is the 10 million you're talking about? How's it related to liquidity?

It's the vanguard limit and they related ir

I am not sure what "withdrawal limit" you are referring to.  Vanguard (and realistically all mutual fund companies) have policies on large transactions that ensure that one person's transaction does not negatively impact other investors.  Different funds will have different rules for what constitutes a large transaction-- $10 M is a reasonable cutoff for when something would qualify as a large transaction for many funds.
Imagine that you're managing a stock market mutual fund with $1 B in assets.  Right now, you've got 99.9% of those funds invested in stocks ($999 M) with another 0.1% ($1 M) in cash.  And let's further say that, on average, the stocks you're holding have appreciated 20% since you purchased them.  Now someone rings up and says they want to withdraw $10 M.
If you want to send that investor $10 M right now, you'd have to sell $9 M worth of the stock you hold.  But if you do that, then the fund is realizing $1.8 M of capital gains (based on average appreciation).  Those $1.8 M would create a tax bill for everyone that holds your mutual fund not just the one person that wanted to withdraw their money.  Vanguard's policy allows them to take a few days to process the request so that they can, for example, hold any new money coming into the fund in cash and pay that money out to the investor that wants the large transaction.  And it allows them to make the redemption in kind-- giving the investor $10 M in stock the fund owns rather than $10 M in cash so that the fund doesn't have to create a taxable event for their shareholders.

Along with your answer.  How many people have 10 million?  How many of those have it all in one fund?  We are talking about less than 1% of the population here.  It also protects the individual investor against fraud.

I seriously doubt that anyone who might have a need for $10M in a rush would have that money in a fund. In that bracket, I would bet you hire your own money manager, and you would probably work more with loans against the equity than with selling equity in any case.
Use the right tool for the task.
$10M is also hardly "Personal Finance", so the question could be argued to be off topic here... except as education in what funds do to protect themselves from attempted manipulation.
